# Java: Cópia de arquivo ficando com 0 bytes

Tags: java

Faço backup do banco de dados normalmente e salvo em uma pasta usando getRuntime().exec().
Utilizo um método, bem simples, para copiar esse arquivo usando FileChannel.

Mas acontece que a cópia fica com 0 bytes. Ele copia o arquivo antes dele estar completo.

Alguma dica de como evitar isso?

Colocando loopings não acho que ficaria trivial, não sei.

Segue abaixo código utilizado para cópia:

```
public static void copyFile(File source, File destination) throws IOException {
        if (destination.exists())
            destination.delete();
        FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
        FileChannel destinationChannel = null;
        try {
            sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
            destinationChannel = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
            sourceChannel.transferTo(0, sourceChannel.size(),
                    destinationChannel);
        } finally {
            if (sourceChannel != null && sourceChannel.isOpen())
                sourceChannel.close();
            if (destinationChannel != null && destinationChannel.isOpen())
                destinationChannel.close();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo essas cópias? Adicione o código.

Comment: Olá Articuno, segue o código na edição da pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: O código funcionou-me corretamente. Qual o tipo de arquivo que está a ser copiado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado a todos!

Analisei todo o código com mais atenção, e o problema mesmo não estava no método que fazia a cópia.

Para resolver, no Runtime que gerava o arquivo foi modificado.
Resumindo, a modificação que resolveu foi:

Antes:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
```

Ficou:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
if(process.waitFor() <= 0) {
 copyFile(origem, destino);
}
```

Com isso a cópia é feita perfeitamente.

Agradeço novamente a atenção de todos!

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a classe byteBuffer da forma abaixo

```
FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
FileChannel destinationChannel = null;
try {
    sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
    destinationChannel = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(32 * 1024);

    while (sourceChannel.read(buff) > 0) {
      buff.flip();
      destinationChannel.write(buff);
      buff.clear();
    }
} finally {
    if (sourceChannel != null && sourceChannel.isOpen())
        sourceChannel.close();
    if (destinationChannel != null && destinationChannel.isOpen())
        destinationChannel.close();
}
```

Comment: Editei o código com as variaveis corretas